# How is the race score determined in multiplayer?

Tags: trials-evolution

I was playing some multiplayer races in Trials: Evolution last night and noticed that sometimes the score at the end of the race would be adjusted down.

What I can't figure out is how this negative adjustment is calculated. It looks like I get negative points for every fault on the course, but then those points don't seem to correspond to the final score.

For example, in one race I ended up with 8 faults and my opponent ended up with 9, so we went into scoring with -8 and -9, but then both our race scores went down by -8. Another time, I had -1 and my opponent had -7, so our scores were adjusted by -1 and -6 respectively.

I can't seem to figure out the pattern here. How are these points determined? Is it affected by who wins the race?

Answer (score 5):

Points are awarded based on two things: Placement and faults.

- The first-place finisher is awarded the base point amount (10 I believe) minus the number of faults they incurred.
- The second-place finisher receives [base point amount - 1] minus number of faults
- Third-place receives [base amount - 2] minus faults
- Fourth-place receives [base amount - 3] minus faults
- If you receive a DNF (Did Not Finish), you will only receive 1 point minus faults

Note: You cannot receive less than 0 points. If you finish first but incur 15 faults, you will not go below 0.

I believe that this is why you're seeing a discrepancy in the standings after a race, the opponent most likely finished before you and got an extra point as a result.

Comment: I don't think number of faults is what's subtracted from the scores. If you fail 50 times and finish first, you won't get 50 points subtracted from the base 10.

Comment: You're correct, there is a minimum score of 0. I tested this today by finishing a local multiplayer match with 15 faults and it did not go below 0. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it doesn't go below zero, but it also doesn't seem to go down by the number of faults. I'll try to grab some screenshots next time I play.